# Is there a way to import backups in NiFi?

Tags: backup, apache-nifi

Using NiFi v0.6.1 is there a way to import backups/archives?

And by backups I mean the files that are generated when you call 
`POST /controller/archive` using the REST api or "Controller Settings" (tool bar button) and then "Back-up flow" (link).

I tried unzipping the backup and importing it as a template but that didn't work. But after comparing it to an exported template file, the formats are reasonably different. But perhaps there is a way to transform it into a template?

At the moment my current work around is to not select any components on the top level flow and then select "create template"; which will add a template with all my components. Then I just export that. My issue with this is it's a bit more tricky to automate via the REST API. I used Fiddler to determine what the UI is doing and it first generates a snippet that includes all the components (labels, processors, connections, etc.). Then it calls create template (`POST /nifi-api/contorller/templates`) using the snippet ID. So the template call is easy enough but generating the definition for the snippet is going to take some work.

Note: Once the following feature request is implemented I'm assuming I would just use that instead:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Configuration+Management+of+Flows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The entire flow for a NiFi instance is stored in a file called `flow.xml.gz` in the conf directory (`flow.xml.tar` in a cluster). The back-up functionality is essentially taking a snapshot of that file at the given point in time and saving it to the `conf/archive` directory. At a later point in time you could stop NiFi and replace `conf/flow.xml.gz` with one of those back-ups to restore the flow to that state.

Templates are a different format from the `flow.xml.gz`. Templates are more public facing and shareable, and can be used to represent portions of a flow, or the entire flow if no components are selected. Some people have used templates as a model to deploy their flows, essentially organizing their flow into process groups and making template for each group. This project provides some automation to work with templates: https://github.com/aperepel/nifi-api-deploy

Answer (score 4):

You just need to stop NiFi, replace the nifi flow configuration file (for example this could be `flow.xml.gz` in the `conf` directory) and start NiFi back up.

If you have trouble finding it check your `nifi.properties` file for the string `nifi.flow.configuration.file=` to find out what you've set this too.

If you are using clustered mode you need only do this on the NCM.

Comment: Regarding clusters:
As I learned from from various posts, [e.g. this](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/66646/view.html), there's no NCM from HDF 2.x.

The correct process is:
1. stop the cluster. 2. remove `flow.xml.gz` from all nodes. 3. copy an archived  `flow.xml.gz` to one of the nodes. 4. start ONLY this node. 5. start the other nodes in the cluster, too.

This way the new `flow.xml.gz` will be propagated to all nodes automatically.